# how to put 2 edit text as textwatch

Tags: android

if I would like to put 2 Edit text as text watch,
how can I put it?
both of them are linked.

Such as if edittext 1 + edittext 2 = ....
meaning
if I add edittext 1 and edittext 2 together,
the outcome wil show it the textviewer

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button saveButton = null;
    EditText dateEdit; 
    EditText priceEdit;
    EditText pumpEdit;
    TextView costView;
    EditText odometerEdit;
    TextView fconView;
     TextWatcher textWatcher;
     String priceEditStr ="",pumpEditStr="";
int result;



    public boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        float price = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("priceEdit"));
        float pump = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("pumpEdit"));

        costView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tcost);
        dateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        priceEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelprice);
        pumpEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelpump);

           priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                        priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                        pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                  if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                  {
                    result = Integer.parseInt(priceEditStr) * Integer.parseInt(pumpEditStr);              
                    costView.setText(" "+result);
                  }

               }
           });

           pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                      {
                        result = Integer.parseInt(priceEditStr) * Integer.parseInt(pumpEditStr);              
                        costView.setText(" "+result);
                      }

               }
           });



        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBTN);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                try
                {
                    dbAdaptor.open();
                    String date = dateEdit.getText().toString();
                    String price = priceEdit.getText().toString();
                    String pump = pumpEdit.getText().toString();
                     String cost = Float.toString(a);
                    String odometer = odometerEdit.getText().toString();
                    String fcon = fconView.getText().toString();
                    dbAdaptor.insertLog(date, price, pump, cost, odometer, fcon);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Fuel Log", e.getMessage());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(dbAdaptor != null)
                        dbAdaptor.close();
                }
            }
        });

    }//oncreate


}//main
```

Comment: So priceEdit for EditText 1 or 2 ? Would you like to show a textview whose result depend on both edit text ?

Comment: whats wrong with et0.addTextChangedListener(l);
et1.addTextChangedListener(l);

Comment: what I mean is
maybe EditText1 is priceEdit, EditText2 is pumpEdit.
there is a TextView , costView to show the result.
The result will be priceEdit * pumpEdit

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee both are different question , do take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233376/calculation-using-textwatch , you may understand the question better.. NOTE: both are different question, thou they seems similar

Comment: @user3210263 I understand your point, you would like to develop when you will write on edit text then it will automatically see next edit text and show the result in textview

Comment: both edit text I will type in a number.
&& the result will show in the textview

Comment: @user3210263 not depend on any button type event, it will show direct result .

Comment: yup.. that's what I meant

Comment: @user3210263 Just wait few times, I will post my code.

Comment: @user3210263 see the solve code, I have develop this code after the clarification and give you the code.

Comment: +1 for your nice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved::

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView; 

     public class EditResult extends Activity {

        //TextWatcher textWatcher; No need 
        EditText priceEdit,pumpEdit;
        TextView costView;
        String priceEditStr="",pumpEditStr="";
         int result;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.edit_sample);

             priceEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             pumpEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
             costView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


            priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                   //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                    if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                         priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                    if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                         pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                   {
                     result = Integer.parseInt(priceEditStr) * Integer.parseInt(pumpEditStr);              
                     costView.setText(" "+result);
                   }

                }
            });

            pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                   //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                    if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                         priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                    if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                         pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                    if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                       {
                         result = Integer.parseInt(priceEditStr) * Integer.parseInt(pumpEditStr);              
                         costView.setText(" "+result);
                       }

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Give me your feedback

Comment: I still trying out. kind of confuse with my code.
I just updated my code.

Comment: ok update this perfectly. It must give you perfect result. Again I tell you that before I have given this code, I have tested it several times.

Comment: I try, because I'm new to android, thus there's alot of things I'm still learning. I'm trying to figure out your code as it seems to be very different from mine that I've updated. As some part, I'm using float instead.

Comment: if possible, u mind helping me with it?while I'm trying it out too

Comment: @user3210263 yaa off course ....... please update your full XML layout and source code . I will give you solve edited code as per your code.

Comment: I think I will take a long time/= I'm new to this coding ...
Sorry about it

Comment: @user3210263 no, it's ok....... But I have some urgent work. But before I go, I will solve your problem.

Comment: HEY!(: I've just done sorting out this code.. but I've a minor error hope that you could help me out..
 String cost = Float.toString(); is having error.
you mind help me to take a look in my code?

Comment: In java it's bad practice to use float. always try to use double. I will update my code within few minutes

Comment: OMG THANKS !!
IT WORKS FINE FOR ME ALREADY!~
thank for the help, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: I've a question to ask,as i've create a dbadapter, even if I used as text watcher in textview, will the data(textview) be able to store in my database?

Comment: @user3210263 yes...... please store the data into string from textview and add this string on abadapter.

Comment: hopefully ,next time if I happen to post any more question, you could help me:)

Comment: hello @, can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236793/how-to-minus-off-the-previous-keyed-valuestore-in-database

Comment: @Chloe I am very busy in my company project, so, no time for me for stackoverflow. I saw your problem. When I get time, then I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this in each edit text view's `TextWatcher`

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                txtViewTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) * Double.parseDouble(edittext_2.getText().toString())));
}
```

Comment: but this is after change text..
w

Comment: You can do the same in `onTextChanged` also but it's better to do in 'afterTextChanged`

Comment: what is the different

Answer (score 0):

Create one textwatcher like this:

```
TextWatcher tw=new TextWatcher(){
            priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {

            }


            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                TextView costView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tcost);
                costView.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(pumpEdit.getText().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(priceEdit.getText().toString())));


            }
        }
```

and add this to both edit text:

```
pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(tw);
priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: so, you trying to say I used priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){, one EDITTEXT, instead of 2?